# How do I open a different domain iFrame link with the InAppBrowser in Ionic?

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework

So I'm creating an app using ionic and the issue I've ran into is when i load in disqus as an iframe. The iframe has links in it such as login and links to other posts etc, however they wont open in android. I've made a script to open all links in the app with the InAppBrowser which works with everything except the iframe.

Now I understand since the iframe is from another domain I wont be able to modify it or catch the links etc, so my question is do you know any other way I can open the links in the iframe using the InAppBrowser?

Edit, to clarify i dont want the links inside the iframe to open inside of it but i want the InAppBrowser to open them up in a new window.

Comment: You will not be able to activate the links of the page in the iframe but you can try accessing the iframe element and change its `src` to the url of pages you need to navigate e.g. url of login page, links page etc..

Comment: i only want the links to open up with the inappbrowser in a new window on the parent tho, not inside of the iframe where links are

Answer (score 0):

I assume Cordova InAppBrowser plugin is installed.

Try the following code:

```
<button class="button button-outline button-royal" ng-click="gotoLink('http://www.google.com')">Open Google</button>
```

In controller file:

```
$scope.gotoLink = function(url) {
  $window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes' );
}
```

You may also see this [tutorial for more information](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/).

Comment: I dont have any problem opening links with the inappbrowser that works fine. The problem im having is opening links which is inside of an iframe loaded in from another domain.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found for making this is implementing from the parent window a function into the loaded iframe, and use this function inside that iframe when you click something or whatever for open that link. For example, you can declare a function (assuming you are using inappbrowser plugin) like:

```
function openLink(url, target, options) {
    window.open(url, target, options);
}
```

And then, put that function into your iframe (`frame` is your iframe):

```
frame.onload = function() {
    this.contentWindow.launchIAB = openLink;
}
```

and finally, use it whenever you need in your iframe code:

```
document.querySelector('a.openLink').on('click', function() {launchIAB(this.href);});
```

Comment: im sorry im new at iframes, but the way i understood it is since i loaded the iframe in from another domain i cant access the code so how would i use it inside the iframe?